# How to compare two dates with current date in Tibco BW?

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

For Example, if you have a date coming from Start activity, How can we compare that date with current date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There actually a function present exactly for that purpose. It is called compare-date or compare-dateTime (if time is also relevant).

The signature of this function is:

compare-date('1980-08-05','1980-09-04')

> returns -1 if first
>
> returns 1 if second
>
> return 0 if both are equal.

In your case this could mean something like:

compare-date($Start/root/Date,current-date())

Answer (score 0):

You can do in following way:
Take two mappers for example, for first use two inputs and give following xpath in an order:

1.For current Date :

```
tib:parse-date("yyyyMMdd",tib:format-date("yyyyMMdd",current-date()))
```

2. For Start Input

   ```
   tib:parse-date("yyyy-MM-dd", $Start/root/Date)
   ```

   and compare it in somewhere in your End's Input like:

   ```
   if ($parseDate/root/currentdate= $parseDate/root/rDate) then substring( 

   $parseDate/root/currentdate - $parseDate/root/Date, 3, 

   string-length(($parseDate/root/currentdate - $parseDate/root/Date))-3) else 
   substring( $parseDate/root/currentdate - $parseDate/root/Date,2, 

   string-length(($parseDate/root/currentdate - $parseDate/root/Date))-2)
   ```